# How to not to add today widget after app install

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, ios10-today-widget

I have developed a "Today Widget" for iOS 10 within my app. After a user downloads my app, this widget is automatically added on display. Is there a way to not to add it to the display. So, if only user wants, he can add by himself.

Comment: The same issue I am also facing while installing an app  widget will be added automatically. But in other app user need to add manually. Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Widgets are not added automatically to notification center. They see an indication a new widget is available, and can choose to add it to their notification center.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible to allow user to install. It will handled by Operating system by default.